# Mockito, JUnit and Map nested in another class

Tags: java, dictionary, junit, mockito

I'm beginner with Mockito and I have problem with creating stub. I have the following interface:

```
public interface IMsgField {
  public String getName();
  public Object getValue();
}
```

One class implements above interface as follows

```
public final class CMsgField implements IMsgField {

  private String name;
  private Object value;

  public CMsgField(String name, Object value) {
   this.name = name;
   this.value = value;
}

 . . .
}
```

And I have one more class :

```
class FieldsWrapper {
    private Map<String, IMsgField> fields = new HashMap<String, IMsgField>();

     . . .
    public Map<String, IMsgField> getFields() {
       return fields;
    }
}
```

I've created the following junit test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    FieldsWrapper fieldsWrapper = mock(FieldsWrapper.class);
    stub(fieldsWrapper.getFields()).toReturn(new HashMap<String, IMsgField>());
    stub(fieldsWrapper.getFields().get("id_object")).toReturn(new CMsgField("id_object", "100"));
     . . .
}
```

And when I ran this test I received the following exception at last line in above test  :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
CMsgField cannot be returned by getFields()
getFields() should return Map
...
```

I don't why, please help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Line `stub(fieldsWrapper.getFields().get("id_object")).toReturn(new CMsgField("id_object", "100"));` looks suspicious. `fieldsWrapper.getFields()` isn't stub. You can just add required `CMsgField` to map. Or mock map itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather proceed this way:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Map<String, IMsgField> stubbedMap = new HashMap<String, IMsgField>();
    stubbedMap.put("id_object", new CMsgField("id_object", "100"));
    FieldsWrapper fieldsWrapper = mock(FieldsWrapper.class);
    stub(fieldsWrapper.getFields()).toReturn(stubbedMap);
}
```

Because you only have to stub fieldsWrapper.getFields().
testMap.get("id_object") is a method call from Map, which is not stubbed, so it can't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would either mock the Map or use a local variable for it :

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Map<String, IMsgField> testMap = new HashMap<String, IMsgField>();
    testMap.put("id_object", new CMsgField("id_object", "100"));
    FieldsWrapper fieldsWrapper = mock(FieldsWrapper.class);
    stub(fieldsWrapper.getFields()).toReturn(testMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do chains of method calls while mocking.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    FieldsWrapper fieldsWrapper = mock(FieldsWrapper.class);
    HashMap<String, IMsgField>() map = new HashMap<String, IMsgField>();
    map.put("id_object", CMsgField("id_object", "100"));
    stub(fieldsWrapper.getFields()).toReturn(map);    
 . . .
}
```